# Suddenly these lines appeared and it no longer accepts anything that I modify in the code and gives an error sign

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP55r.png)

(send_keys and click) stoped from work after this line appeared

I tried to update the library, I also deleted the VS and re-downloaded it. I also deleted and re-downloaded the extensions , but nothing works .help me please

Comment: Can you please add your code as formatted text? if you add code as an image, it makes it difficult for people to find your question from searching and makes it difficult to understand or reproduce your error

Comment: @DerekO thanks mr derek . I'm still a beginner and your advice is very important to me. thank you very much . After trying it turned out that my computer has updated my Windows and the Python version is no longer suitable for running codes. Thank you again